# How to get elements (or text) in the same row as current selected checkbox?

Tags: jquery, dom

So far I have this which gets me the rowIndex but haven't figured out how to get the other 2 fields in the same row (can be either inputs or plaintext wrapped in td):

```
$('.chkbox').click(function(){
        if($(this).is(':checked')){
            var checkbox = $(this);
            var rowIndex = $(checkbox).closest('tr')[0].rowIndex;
            alert(rowIndex);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is a common wrapping element then you could just use that? I imagine the other elements are surrounded by 's so you could just do:

```
if ($(this).is(":checked"))
{
    var checkbox = $(this);
    other_elements_in_the_row = checkbox.closest("td").siblings().children();
}


<tr>
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <p>Hello!</p>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" value=", World" />
    </td>
</tr>
```

This would return the `<p>Hello</p>` and the other input.

Comment: If I do other_elements[0] I get the input but it skips the "Hello" any idea why?

Comment: it was the missing <p> that was causing me the problem, thanks! =)

Answer (score 0):

You can find the row then use that to [scope the context](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery1) of another jQuery call to find which ever child text / values you like.

```
$('.chkbox').click(function(){
    if($(this).is(':checked')){
        var checkbox = $(this);
        var row = $(checkbox).closest('tr');
        var stuffToUpdate = $(":your_super_awesome_selector",row);
        $.each(stuffToUpdate, function(i,val){ 
         alert( val );
        });
    }
});
```